# DynamoDb - write transaction conditional on state of another table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Let's say you're modelling a system in which users can own certain items. Users can also place bids to buy an item from its current owner. I need to be able to store an arbitrary number of bids per item.

Four common operations needed are:

- Operation 1: Fetch all bids made by a given user
- Operation 2: Fetch all bids for items owed by a given user
- Operation 3: Insert a new bid for a given item
- Operation 4: Accept a bid, in which case the OwnerUserId of the item transfers to the new owner

I'm trying to come up with a clever way of modelling this in DynamoDB. So far, I've been thinking of two tables with a rough layout as follows:

```
Item {
  Guid ItemId;
  Guid OwnerUserId;
  /* ... Some other data ... */
}

Bid {
   Guid SomeUniqueBidId;
   Guid ItemId;
   Guid OwnerUserId;
   Guid BidFromUserId;
   double Value;
}
Primary key (BidFromUserId, ItemId)
Seconadary index(OwnerUserId, SomeUniqueBidId)
```

- Operation 1 can be fulfilled by querying Bid's primary key
- Operation 2 could be fulfilled by Bid's secondary index
- Operation 3 and 4.. are a pain.

In order to insert an item, I'd need to do either

1. Some transaction that reads the current OwnerUserId from item, and uses that value to populate the "OwnerUserId" field when inserting an entry into Bid. Or,
2. Query the current OwnerUserId from Item beforehand, and then do a write transaction that has some form of condition check that verifies if the current entry in "Item" for the given ItemId corresponds to the previously queried OwnerUserId

Either involves de facto joining an otherwise unrelated table into the query - I have not found any way to do this in DynamoDb. Is there any way?

Alternatively, is there any good/better way to do this?

I have thought about adding the bids as a collection property to "Item" directly. However, that doesn't seem feasible due to DynamoDB's byte size limit per entry, which would effectively number the maximum amount of auctions for an item.

Instead o storing "OwnerUserId" in the Bids table, I could also query all items for a given user first, and then fetch Bids specifically for those items on the fly. That seems bad though as I don't think DynamoDB efficiently supports "CONTAINS" queries, so I might end up churning through RCUs quite hard this way (each item owned by a user would result in 1 individual query to the Bids table!)

I'm curious to hear some better approaches, if there are any!

Comment: I'm confused why you need to transactionally read the OwnerUserId for an item or conditionally update it. Isn't it immutable? So you read it at some point and denormalize the value into the bid for convenient usage during the query. What's the issue exactly? If the OwnerUserId is mutable then you have bigger issues than the initial insert, because you have to update every place you've denormaliezed the value.

Comment: @hunterhacker My bad, I should have pointed this out (and have just edited to question to do so) - yes, OwnerUserId is mutable and might be updated if a bid is accepted. Unfortunately i think that even does rule out my only idea that i thought was feasible so far as I wouldn't be able to update the Bid table by hash key only (without range key)

Comment: Seems to me if I bid on your item, it's a bid on your item and the bid record can store and keep that fact forever, even if after the sale it becomes my item. If you really need "live" ownership tracking for the query, then you probably shouldn't denormalize (because a frequently sold item will need to update an ever-growing list of historic bids), which means accepting the multiple queries.